# AngularJS - how to have a directive with a dynamic sub-directive

Tags: angularjs

Really struggling with this - have tried every way I can think of.  Hopefully, somebody can help.

I have a directive which creates the outline of a custom control for me.  The central part of the custom control is to be represented by a further dynamically-generated directive based on the value of a scope variable on the outer directive.  The scope variable contains the name of the inner directive.  I am doing this because my page will have multiple dynamically-generated elements all with a common layout but different inner content.

i.e. an example of my outer directive:

```
<div data-inner="{{inner}}">
    <!-- div content here --->
<div {{inner}} />
```

`{{inner}}` is set to the name of a further directive - in this case `search`.  My page should therefore become:

```
<div data-inner="search">
    <!-- div content here --->
<div search />
```

with `search` on the lower div also being replaced by the content of that directive.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Here's a basic [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanwest/5wEjD/1/) representing the issue I have - note the third div is not displayed.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write </div search> instead of <div search/>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have create a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpKwb/2/).

These are the directives.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="one">
    <div class="one"></div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="two">
     <div class="two"></div>
</script>
```

And here you do dynamic loading

```
<div ng-repeat='template in inner' ng-include='template'></div>
```

See if this helps you, and solves your purpose. I am making each directive into a template and then using ng include

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much.  If I could pass you a virtual gold star I would, and it's a nice elegant solution too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpKwb/12/

You can use ngSwitch

```
<div ng-repeat='template in inner'>
    <div ng-switch on="template">
        <div ng-switch-when="one">
            <div class='one'></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="two">
            <div class='two'></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: does this not create both templates and only plays with their visibility?