# Parse directive when it is set inside of a ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Wondering if it is possible to make a directive inside of ng-repeat

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-{{item.type}}="item">
</div>
```

such that the result is

```
<div data-link="item"><div>
<div data-video="item"></div>
```

In other words I want the directive to be dynamic.
Is this possible?

Comment: I think I can link this to this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264534/dynamically-adding-directives-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, but you can create a directive that is replaced with the directive you want:

```
myApp.directive('makeDirective', function($compile){
    return {
        compile: function CompilingFunction(element, attrs) {
            var directiveName = attrs.makeDirective;
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope) {
                    element.replaceWith($compile('<div data-' + directiveName + ' ></div>')(scope));
                }
            }

        }
    }
})
```

Use it like this:

```
<div make-directive="video"></div>
```

To pass attributes you would need to update the maker directive.

[Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1377/](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1377/)

Comment: Yeah I discovered it was not possible. I did prefer the ng-require="template" I found somewhere else but this is a good idea as well. I actually had thought of this but it was going to be too "hacky" for what I am trying to do. None the less I award you the points because it is one a very good alternative in general.