# Adding dynamic colors in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Just trying to get a handle on angularJS as was building a simple little app where you can make a list of people and in the list their names are colored. The color is chosen by a select drop-down box.

The trouble is any way I try to add the new color to a style I run into trouble. At this point names get added to the list correctly, but they don't get colored correctly and I get the following error:

```
    Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column null of the expression [{color:] starting at [{color:].
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=%7Bcolor%3A&p4=%7Bcolor%3A
        at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
        at Parser.throwError (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10266:11)
        at Parser.primary (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10239:14)
        at Parser.unary (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10492:19)
        at Parser.multiplicative (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10475:21)
        at Parser.additive (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10466:21)
        at Parser.relational (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10457:21)
        at Parser.equality (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10448:21)
        at Parser.logicalAND (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10439:21)
        at Parser.logicalOR (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10427:21) <li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-style="{color:" "stylecolor(player)"}="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
```

Which I think means player.color is coming back null? If there is a way to do this without the function call that would be preferable I was just trying emulate this solution:
[dynamically adding directives in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264534/dynamically-adding-directives-in-ng-repeat)

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Scratch Snake</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
<script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js">  </script>

<!-- Bootstrap files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"> </script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-controller = "PlayerAdditionCtrl">
<ul class="list-group">Players:
<li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-style =  {color: "styleColor(player)"} > {{player.name}} </li>
</ul>

<div id="playerEntry"> 
        <p> 
    <label for="playername">Name: </label><input id="playername" class="form-control" type="text" name="playername" ng-model="playername"> 
            <select id="playerColor" ng-model="playercolor"> 
              <option value="#f00">Red</option> 
              <option value="#00f">Blue</option> 
              <option value="#0f0">Green</option> 
              <option value="#ff0">Yellow</option> 
            </select> 
        </p> 
        <button type="button" class = "btn btn-primary" id="addPlayerBtn" ng-click="addPlayer()">Add Player</button> 
        <button type="button" class = "btn btn-success" id="doneBtn" onclick="moveToGame();">All Done!</button> 

        <button type="button" class = "btn btn-info" id="defaultsBtn" onclick="loadDefaults();">Load Defaults</button> 
        <br>  
</div>
<!-- In production use:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my controller:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('PlayerAdditionCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.players = [];

        //add a player
        $scope.addPlayer = function()
        {
            $scope.players.push(
                {
                    name: $scope.playername, 
                    color: $scope.playercolor
                });
        }

        $scope.styleColor = function (player)
        {
            return { color: player.color }
        }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

`$scope.styleColor()` in your controller

change

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-style =  {color: "styleColor(player)"} > {{player.name}} </li>
```

to

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-style="{color: player.color}" > {{player.name}} </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-style =  {color: "styleColor(player)"} > {{player.name}} </li>
```

to

```
<li ng-repeat="player in players" style="color: {{player.color}};"> {{player.name}} </li>
```

If you stick with ng-style, two-way data binding will update every player to the selected color. Without using angular.copy, changing your data structure, or doing something else to break two-way data binding, it won't be possible to have players be different colors.

Here's a working Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wEpKzN?p=preview