# dynamically adding classes in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angular and have been having a tough time with this issue. I'm using masonry to build a dynamic collection of images and videos in an ng-repeat and would like to randomize the sizing classes I use for images. I.e. if an item in the ng-repeat is an image, apply one of two classes to it.

So far I have this for the template:

```
<div class="modalVid" ng-repeat="m in mediaList | filter:mediaType track by $index">
<a ng-if="m.type=='video'" zf-open="basicModal_{{$index}}" class="grid-item grid-item--video" ng-click="modalOpen()" style="background-image: url({{m.thumb}}); background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></a>
<a ng-if="m.type=='image'" zf-open="basicModal_{{$index}}" ng-class="grid-item" random-class ng-click="modalOpen()" style="background-image: url({{m.thumb}}); background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></a>
    <div ng-if="m.type=='video'"  class="" zf-modal="" id="basicModal_{{$index}}">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="{{iFrameSrc(v.videoid)}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="m.type=='image'" zf-modal="" class="large" id="basicModal_{{$index}}">
        <img src="{{m.screenshot}}">
    </div>
```

I'm using a directive called random-class to insert the class:

```
angular.module('mfApp')
.directive('randomClass', randomClass);

function randomClass(){

    return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require:'^mfMason',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

            var classArr = ['grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2', 'grid-item--width1 grid-item--height1'];
            var newClass = classArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * classArr.length)];

            elem.addClass(newClass);


    }
    }

}
```

And the masonry wrapper is itself a directive:

```
angular.module('mfApp')
.directive('mfMason', mfMason);

function mfMason(){
    return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude:true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/masonry_build.html',
    controller:function($scope){
        $scope.classes = ['grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2', 'grid-item--width1 grid-item--height1'];
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr){
        var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $grid.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          columnWidth: 182,
          gutter:1
        });
        });


      }
    };
}
```

Sadly it's not working. I have tried using some of the solutions from other questions, e.g. [dynamically adding directives in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264534/dynamically-adding-directives-in-ng-repeat)but to no avail.
There are clearly many things about Angular I don't understand in terms of directives etc, so any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`require:'^mfMason'` is looking for a **controller** named `mfMason`, but you have a **directive** named `mfMason`. Try removing the `require:'^mfMason',` from your `randomClass` directive and see if it works then.

I'm surprised you weren't seeing an error regarding this in the console.

**Update**
[Here is a sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79mboq2b/) demonstrating that it works. I made the `<div>`s wide and with a border to make it easier to right-click and inspect in Chrome dev tools. I also output the `class` attribute after randomly adding your classes.

Here's the javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('randomClass', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var classArr = ['grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2', 'grid-item--width1 grid-item--height1'];
                var newClass = classArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * classArr.length)];
                element.addClass(newClass);
                element.text(element.attr('class'));
            }
        }
    });
```

And here's the html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div random-class class="something" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div random-class class="something" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div random-class class="something" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div random-class class="something" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div random-class class="something" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div random-class class="something" style="border: 1px solid black; height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! That's an unfortunate byproduct of hacking away at different solutions and ending up with frankenstein code. It doesn't work without it either though

Comment: @defmigroggie I was able to get it working. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Lex! I definitely see it working in your fiddle. I think the problem I'm having is that I'm importing the random-class directive into another directive and I'm doing that incorrectly somehow. So unfortunately this doesn't work for me.