# Dynamically Generate Custom Directive within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a set of custom chart directives such as `<div class='ico-graph'/>`, and I'm trying to generate a stack of them based on config contained in `icograph` consisting of directive name, data and title;

```
<div ng-repeat="icograph in vm.icographs" ng-class="icograph.graph"  title="icograph.title"
    values="icograph.data">
</div>
```

The directives themselves support `EAC` so can be elements, attributes or class definition, eg;

```
angular.module('myApp.directives')
    .directive("icoGraph", [function () {
        return { 
            restrict: "EAC",
            scope: {
                type: "=",
                title: "=",
                values: "=",

            },
            template: "<ng-include src=\"'/ng/app/views/directives/IcoGraph.htm'\"></ng-include>",
            link: icoGraphLinker({}), // inits the linker function which returns a link function
        }
    }])
}
```

#### Problem

Now these directives work fine when defined statically but I want to choose the chart type based on the tag name contained in `icograph.graph`. I'm trying to set the `class` (choose the directive) based on the `graph` property in `icograph` as you can see in the HTML above.

This works;

```
class="ico-graph"
class="{{'ico-graph'}}"
```

But these don't (I get no chart);

```
class="{{icograph.graph}}"
ng-class="{{'nupe-ico-graph'}}"
ng-class="{{icograph.graph}}"
ng-class="icograph.graph"
```

Also, if I emit `{{icograph.graph}}` in the page I can verify that it contains the string `"ico-graph"`

I'm assuming that either the order of evaluation or scope is somehow the problem with ng-repeat, but I can't quite see the issue.

Actually, I suspect this has to do with compilation. Possibly ng-repeat is taking a copy of my node definition prior to interpolation and it's not being treated as a directive during dom transformation. If somebody can provide a better explanation, and perhaps a workaround of how I can achieve this without using a single directive that does all chart types (like I'm doing at the moment) it would be a useful post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had provided a plunker\fiddle it would have been better. But still let me take a shot. What you need to do is to create a template in you html like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" class="template" id="ico-graph">
     <span data-ico-graph="">
</script>
```

Now your code becomes

```
<div ng-repeat="icograph in vm.icographs"  title="icograph.title"
    values="icograph.data">
          <ng-include src='icograph.graph'/>
</div>
```

Currently what you are doing does not render the directive because angular does not see it during the html compilation stage. What it sees is a standard databinding expression

Comment: Sorry, I haven't stripped down the code enough for a fiddle yet. Thanks for the stab, although I can't see how the embedded template works. My issue is that I need to be able to choose the directive (and therefore template) based on the binding expression in ng-repeat. In other words, the class property needs to resolve to whatever string is contained in 'icograph.graph' where that string will be the name of the directive I want it to emit.

Comment: I may work if you try, until i am missing something essential. Instead to resolving to a class property, we are trying to resolve to a template, which is nothing more than a directive container. When Angular will do ng-include and see the template html, it would compile the correct directive.

Comment: I did this for someone else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643601/angularjs-how-to-have-a-directive-with-a-dynamic-sub-directive/14648641#14648641 which seems similar

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I think I might have discovered what's wrong. My icograph config is being fetched over ajax and it fails because the value isn't bound at compilation time. I just ran into a different issue caused by a similar problem. I'll have to see if I can generate a small repro fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-include` to load different directives. This is the simplest way. All other way s I have seen (and implemented) have been messier. It annoys me to create an HTML template just to load each directive, that I need to apply dynamically, but it works well.

Here is my widget code fore example:

```
<div ng-repeat="widget in widgets track by $index" ng-include="widget.url" class="widget-container" ng-class="widget.widget_type.config.height +' ' + widget.widget_type.config.width">
</div>
```

Then I set the widget.url to a template containing just the right directive.