# How can I generate on the fly directives in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to be able to take an array of strings, and then create directives based upon those strings. Either element or attribute will work fine but can't seem to get it working.

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modules.directives">
    <div {{module.directive}}></div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="module in modules.directives">
    <{{module.directive}}></{{module.directive}}>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="module in modules.directives">
    <{{module.directive}} />
</div>
```

Can't get any of these to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do so ?

Comment: Are you directives fixed and predefined in the code?

Comment: Yes, predefined. If I manually type out `<test-module></test-module>` it works. Even `<div class="test-module"></div>` works. But `class="{{module.directive}}"` doesn't work.

Comment: @ovmjm the modules are controlled by a dynamic source, so I can't hard code anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a directive that would *proxy* another directive like so

```
<div proxy="'ng-if'" proxy-value="'foo'"></div>
<div ng-init="n='ng-if'; v='foo';" proxy="n" proxy-value="v"></div>
```

that would both be equivalent to

```
<div ng-if="foo"></div>
```

the `proxy` directive definition would be

```
app.directive('proxy', function ($parse, $injector) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var nameGetter = $parse(attrs.proxy);
        var name = nameGetter(scope);
        var value = undefined;
        if (attrs.proxyValue) {
          var valueGetter = $parse(attrs.proxyValue);
          value = valueGetter(scope);
        }
        var directive = $injector.get(name + 'Directive')[0];
        if (value !== undefined) {
            attrs[name] = value;
        }
        return directive.compile(element, attrs, null)(scope, element, attrs);
    };
});
```

This is actually kind of a fun directive to write once in a life. :-) but it lacks a lot of the native directive features (for instance *template*, *templateUrl*, *controller*, etc). All those features are available in the original Angular source code in a private function called `applyDirectivesToNode`, so it is easy to copy/paste some parts, but ugly... I have written a demo matching your usecase [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tutGZ/2/).

Another solution, if you don't mind your proxied directive does not share the same element as the `proxy` directive's one, would be to `$compile` a dynamic template at runtime that you would include. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2MW39/1/).

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. Got this working, will need a bit of fiddling with on my end but this works. Thank you!

Comment: Quick sub-question, when I return a templateUrl for the directive, I get a `Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'` error. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: What do you mean by *return* ? Any fiddle to investigate ?

Comment: Ignore the extra `]`, that's been removed. I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile' at http://localhost/common/directives/proxy.js:17:30`

Comment: Your version works fine, adds the class perfectly. I just cannot seem to import the template. http://pastebin.com/L49GL1FR

Comment: Better example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tutGZ/2/ - when it's ran properly, it returns the template. When the proxy runs it, it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Your need concerns only pure template directive ?

Comment: Template and controller. Modules.

Comment: Because I can think of a way to proxy directive features like *template* or *templateUrl*, this is fun, I already have a proxy for templates, but it is getting ugly. Maybe if you explain what you really want to achieve we might find a more direct solution to your problem.

Comment: Alright, here goes. I will query an API and get a list of 'features' to load. This list will be `$scope.directives`. I then want to be able to loop through that list of directives and display them on the page. The directives will be inside modules which will be added to the app. These may be as simple as a hello world or as advanced as a spreadsheet. The main thing is that I can control what is shown from a single string. Does this make sense?

Comment: OK I added a paragraph to my answer. This might work for your usecase. However, let me understand, do you really need *directives* ? or any other *widget* system would fit your root need ? Because maybe just pairs of partial/controller are what you are really looking for..

Comment: If there is another method of modularly plugging in a functionality where I can have a controller and a template and then dynamically showing it then I'd go with that. Looking at your example, I think that might work. I will test this tomorrow and let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is a demo with partial/controller widgets  http://jsfiddle.net/sMntS/1/ . It is good if you target standalone widgets with complex UI. Directives are better if you target smaller reusable and composable widget components. I think.

Comment: What are your opinions on bootstrapping a new angular app for each widget? That way they are totally isolated. That appears to be the way that the angularjs website do it for the examples. Thanks for all the feedback by the way!

Comment: Sure it seems to be a great idea if you target such a level of isolation. Great great :) I didn't know it was possible. Thanks! Here is a good link on the subject https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/lhbrIG5aBX4/4hYnzq2eGZwJ

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` can help you. The approach would be to define a template for each of the directives. Something like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" class="template" id="test-module">
<test-module></test-module>
</script>
```

Then in ng-repeat do

```
<div ng-repeat="module in modules.directives">
     <ng-include src="module.directive">
</div
```

If the template `id` matches with `module.directive` that directive would get rendered.

Comment: Would every module have to be hard-coded within the script tags though?

Comment: Name of the directives should be known before hand, and should be registered using a template with matching script `id`

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. I should probably mention that this is inside another directive. Tried `<script type="text/ng-template" class="template" id="test-module"><test-module></test-module></script><ng-include src="test-module">` without any of the ng-repeat but no dice.

Comment: This script should be defined in html. You should be able to get this object even by doing `$('#test-module')`. It should be part of DOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643601/angularjs-how-to-have-a-directive-with-a-dynamic-sub-directive/14648641#14648641