# AngularJS proxy directive

Tags: angularjs, interface, proxy, directive, facade

I am trying to create a proxy directive like so:

```
<x-field x-purpose="choice" x-values="data.countries" ng-model="model.country"/>
```

Where the `field` directive forwards this to another directive, causing the following replacement:

```
<x-choiceField x-values="data.countries" ng-model="model.country"/>
```

[note:] the ng-model could be replaced by a reference to some new isolated scope.

The "field purpose" directive decides which implementation to use (e.g. drop-down/listbox/autocomplete?) based on how many values there are to choose from, client device size, etc - ultimately resulting in something like this:

```
<select ng-model="model.country" ng-options="data.countries">
```

This design is largely out of curiosity rather than for any practical reason, I am interested in how to achieve it rather than whether it is actually a good idea from a performance/simplicity point of view...

After reading [https://stackoverflow.com/a/18895441/1156377], I have something like this:

```
function proxyDirective($injector, $parse, element) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var target = element.camelCase(attrs.name + '-field');
        var model = attrs.ngModel;
        var value = $parse(model);
        var directive = $injector.get(target);
        /* Bind ngModel to new isolated scope "value" property */
        scope.$watch(model, function () {
            ???
        });
        /* Generate new directive element */
        var pElement = angular.element.html('');
        var pAttrs = {
            value: ???
        };
        /* Forward to new directive */
        return directive.compile(element, attrs, null)(scope, element, attrs);
    };
}

function alphaFieldDirective() {
    return {
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<input type="text" ng-value="forwarded value?">'
    };
}

function betaFieldDirective() {
    return {
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<textarea attributes? >{{ value }}</textarea>'
    };
}
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve the forwarding or binding.  This is my first forage into Angular directives, and it doesn't seem to be a particularly popular way of using them!

The purpose of this is to separate the purpose of a form field from its appearance/implementation, and to provide one simple directive for instantiating fields.

Comment: Solved it, I'll post the answer tomorrow when I've got the demo working fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this via a service which proxies directives:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7779/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Directive proxying</h1>
    <proxy target="bold" text="Bold text"></proxy>
    <h1>Attribute forwarding</h1>
    <proxy target="italic" style="color: red;" text="Red, italic text"></proxy>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('directiveProxyService', directiveProxyService)
    .directive('proxy', dirProxy)
    .directive('bold', boldDirective)
    .directive('italic', italicDirective)
    ;

function directiveProxyService($compile) {
    return function (target, scope, element, attrs, ignoreAttrs) {
        var forward = angular.element('<' + target + '/>');
        /* Move attributes over */
        _(attrs).chain()
            .omit(ignoreAttrs || [])
            .omit('class', 'id')
            .omit(function (val, key) { return key.charAt(0) === '$'; })
            .each(function (val, key) {
                element.removeAttr(attrs.$attr[key]);
                forward.attr(attrs.$attr[key], val);
            });
        $compile(forward)(scope);
        element.append(forward);
        return forward;
    };
}

function dirProxy(directiveProxyService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000000,
        replace: true,
        template: '<span></span>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            directiveProxyService(attrs.target, scope, element, attrs, ['target']);
        }
    };
}

function boldDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<i>{{ text }}</i>',
        scope: { text: '@' }
    };
}

function italicDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<i>{{ text }}</i>',
        scope: { text: '@' }
    };
}
```