# Rendering and injecting dynamic templates in a loop inside controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I want to write a form builder app with angular.
The app will allow the user to build simple HTML forms with drag'n'drop elements.

I thought it would be good to have the elements templates stored as separate html files or just as strings.

If for example I have the following data:

```
$scope.formFields = [
   {type: "fTextbox", name: "textbox1", label: "First name"},
   {type: "fDropdown", name: "dropdown1", label: "Country"},
   {type: "fCheckbox", name: "terms1", label: "TermsAndConditions"},
   ...
];
```

I could also have a a dictionary somewhere to store the templates and map them to the form elements.

```
{
    fTextbox: "/templates/elements/textbox.html",
    fDropdown: "/templates/elements/dropdown.html",
    fCheckbox: "/templates/elements/checkbox.html",
    ...
}
```

How would I go about looping through it and appending the right templates to the view?

[Edit]
I just need the general approach to such tasks in angular.
So far I only came across the ng-switch for the template, but that's not a desirable solution because there could be quite a lot of types of form elements and the template will get really messy.

Comment: Directive feels quite natural for this task. `<element type="fTextbox"></element>`.

Comment: Thanks! But how  to insert them into the view dynamically based on the current model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-include` to inject the templates dynamically based on name, such as

`<div ng-include='template.fTextbox'/>
<div ng-include='template.fCheckbox'/>`

You can write directives too but still you would need to wrap them up into `ng-include`. See my answer [AngularJS - how to have a directive with a dynamic sub-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643601/angularjs-how-to-have-a-directive-with-a-dynamic-sub-directive/14648641#14648641)

Comment: I am integrating your solution into my current project and I was wondering if there is any way to keep the directive templates outside of the main template? *where you have the `<script type="text/template">` in your jsfiddle

Comment: I believe they can be anywhere inside the `ng-app` and can be loaded from server also.